# missing token 'content-type' in cors header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cors

I am trying to build a social App. I am using MEANJS boilerplate. and handling requests well. But when it comes to the search, I wanted to integrate ElasticSearch in to this MEAN app.

so I followed
http://www.sitepoint.com/building-recipe-search-site-angular-elasticsearch/
 link for initial setup. I wrote controllers and and indexed my mongodb models to elastic search db successfully.

and I verified elastic search by going to localhost:9200 by querying models. 
My mean js app is running in localhost:3000.

Everything is fine but one thing that stopped me was CORS. CORS configuration with elastic search to get results.[this is my request from localhost:3000 to localhost 9200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ginIx.png)
To allow the CORS I have to configure my elasticsearch yaml file. and I have done that by adding

```
 http.cors.enabled : true
  http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
  http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
  http.cors.allow-headers : origin, X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, accept
  http.cors.Max-Age: "1728000"
```

But still I cant access the localhost:9200 server.

I get this error.

Any help in detail is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9200/. (Reason: missing token 'content-type' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).
```

Comment: Are you sure you're sending content-type token in header Access-Control-Allow-Headers?